# Convolutional neural network: why is my training accuracy suddenly dropping?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, convolution

I am trying to understand this behaviour in my shallow CNN (only one layer followed by a sigmoid classification layer. I am training on about 2000 images per class. My learning rate was 0.01 and I was using binary cross-entropy. The final test accuracy was only 54% (essentially no greater than chance). What I don't understand is the pattern of training accuracy - I thought perhaps my learning rate was too high so I lowered it to 1e-3. Again the network rapidly gains training accuracy followed by a validation accuracy of 1 and then starts dropping like stone on the next Epoch (and then up again).

I wonder if by binary cross entropy is returning a NaN value but I am not sure how to check for that and I don't have an intuition about the impact that may have.

```
[INFO] training network...
Epoch 1/4
44/44 [==============================] - 391s 9s/step - loss: 0.0620 - acc: 0.9943 - val_loss: 1.0960e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 2/4
44/44 [==============================] - 459s 10s/step - loss: 7.0132 - acc: 0.5625 - val_loss: 5.5104 - val_acc: 0.6562
Epoch 3/4
44/44 [==============================] - 246s 6s/step - loss: 16.0302 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 16.0302 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/4
44/44 [==============================] - 250s 6s/step - loss: 0.3628 - acc: 0.9774 - val_loss: 1.0960e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
```

EDIT:

Just to add, when I changed the learning ratee to 1e-3, I got the exact same result as above - as in precisely the same losses and accuracies.

Comment: Did you check the input of your sigmoid? It could be that you are getting too big (or too small) values which can cause numerical error. In this case you could need to regularize.